# Check the User Whether Exist in Azure AD from WPF application

Tags: c#, azure-active-directory

I have a WPF application and its authentication is AzureAD. If any new user comes then first we will add that user in Azure AD and after that we will add the same user to our WPF application. While adding that user to WPF we need to verify that user is present in Azure

Steps
1. Network Admin creating a user in Azure AD
2. Our project Admin add that user to our client in Azure
3. Project Admin login to our WPF application using azure authentication and adding this user
4. At that time we need to recheck the new user is present in azureAD.

It means project admin login to WPF application using Azure authentication [His userid, ticket, clientid etc are available] and he trying to check a user present it Azure AD [New users name is available, but password will not know by this Admin].

Please help me to write a c# code for solving this problem.

Comment: SO is not a coding service. You should research, try to do something then if you have any particular code problem, you can ask. But where is the code? I don't see any.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regarding the issue, please refer the following code

```
//install Active Directory Authentication Library (ADAL) and Azure Active Directory Graph Client Library
    public static ActiveDirectoryClient GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication()
        {
            Uri servicePointUri = new Uri(ResourceId);
            Uri serviceRoot = new Uri(servicePointUri,tenant);
            ActiveDirectoryClient activeDirectoryClient = new ActiveDirectoryClient(serviceRoot,
                async () => await AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication());
            return activeDirectoryClient;
        }

        public static async Task<string> AcquireTokenAsyncForApplication()
        {
            return await GetTokenForApplication();
        }

        /// <summary>
        /// Get Token for Application.
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns>Token for application.</returns>
        public static async Task<string> GetTokenForApplication()
        {

                AuthenticationContext authenticationContext = new AuthenticationContext(
                    authority,
                    false);

                // Configuration for OAuth client credentials 


                    ClientCredential clientCred = new ClientCredential(
                        clientId,
                        cred);
                    AuthenticationResult authenticationResult =
                        await authenticationContext.AcquireTokenAsync(ResourceId, clientCred);
                   var TokenForApplication = authenticationResult.AccessToken;


            return TokenForApplication;
        }

        public async Task<object> Getuser()
        {

            ActiveDirectoryClient client = GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
            var userLookupTask = client.Users.Where(
         user => user.UserPrincipalName.Equals(
        "", StringComparison.CurrentCultureIgnoreCase)).ExecuteSingleAsync();
            User result =(User) await userLookupTask;
            return result;

        }

        public async Task Adduser() {
            ActiveDirectoryClient client = GetActiveDirectoryClientAsApplication();
            var newUser = new User()
            {
                // Required settings
                DisplayName = "",
                UserPrincipalName = "",
                PasswordProfile = new PasswordProfile()
                {
                    Password = "H@ckMeNow!",
                    ForceChangePasswordNextLogin = false
                },
                MailNickname = "",
                AccountEnabled = true,

                // Some (not all) optional settings
                GivenName = "",
                Surname = "",
                JobTitle = "",
                Department = "",
                City = "",
                State = "",
                Mobile = "",
            };

            await client.Users.AddUserAsync(newUser);

        }
```

For more details, please refer to https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/aadgraphteam/2014/12/11/announcing-azure-ad-graph-api-client-library-2-0/